# installing a 2nd Java protobuf version

Tags: java, macos, protocol-buffers

I initially installed protobuf 2.5.0 but now need the ability to run 2.4.1. I'm trying to figure out how to install 2.4.1 when I already have 2.5.0 installed.  I ran 
`./configure --prefix=/usr` since 2.5.0 is installed to /usr/local but then `make` blows up:

```
$ make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in .
Making all in src
2.4.1 -I. --cpp_out=. google/protobuf/unittest.proto google/protobuf/unittest_empty.proto google/protobuf/unittest_import.proto google/protobuf/unittest_mset.proto google/protobuf/unittest_optimize_for.proto google/protobuf/unittest_embed_optimize_for.proto google/protobuf/unittest_custom_options.proto google/protobuf/unittest_lite.proto google/protobuf/unittest_import_lite.proto google/protobuf/unittest_lite_imports_nonlite.proto google/protobuf/unittest_no_generic_services.proto google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_test_bad_identifiers.proto
make[2]: 2.4.1: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [unittest_proto_middleman] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is the best way to install 2.4.1 when 2.5.0 is already installed?

Comment: Are you sure that's exactly the `configure` command-line you used?  It looks like you may have added `--with-protoc=2.4.1`, which is nonsensical (`--with-protoc` does not take a version number).